# rtk query , How to assign data will received from request to variable is initialized with useState?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

How to assign data which received from request to variable is initialized with useState hook ?

** this is the define of the service which call request **

```
export const diligenceApi = createApi({
    reducerPath: 'diligenceApi',
    baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
        baseUrl: environment.apiUrl,
    }),
    tagTypes: ['Diligence'],
    endpoints: (builder) => ({
        updateCoverage: builder.mutation<DiligenceDTo[], { organizationName: string,              updateCoverageRequest: any }>({
            query: (arg) => {
                const { organizationName, updateCoverageRequest } = arg;
                return {
                    url: `${organizationName}/Charts/Coverage`,
                    method: "POST",
                    body: updateCoverageRequest,
                }
            },
            invalidatesTags: ['Diligence']
        }), 
    })
})

export const { useUpdateCoverageMutation } = diligenceApi
```

** I want to assign data variable with data that's will received from the request after the request finish **

**like await it then **

```
const { dashboardFilter, organization } = useStateContext();
  const [data, setData] = useState<DiligenceDTo[]>();

  const [updateCoverage, { data: coverageData, isLoading, isSuccess, isError}] = useUpdateCoverageMutation();


  const getData =  async() => {
    await updateCoverage({ organizationName: organization?.name, updateCoverageRequest: dashboardFilter });
    
  }
  

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!organization?.name) return;
     getData();
  }, [dashboardFilter, organization]);
```

Comment: Did you try `setData`?

Comment: yes and didn't accept cause it may be infinite loop

Answer (score 0):

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (!isSuccess) return;

    coverageData.then(({ data }) => setData(data));
}, [ coverageData, isSuccess]);
```